# Excel Data Validation: Same List, Different Sheets, Select 1 and Update the other

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, excel-2016

Is it possible in excel to have 2 similar data validation lists on different sheets and once you selected a value in Sheet 1, the list in Sheet 2 will be updated with same value selected on the previous sheet? Non-VB solutions are preferred; otherwise, let me know if it's not possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about a formula like `=Sheet1!A1`, say in `sheet2!A1`?

Answer (score 0):

here is what  I have done :

1. At B4 in Sheet1 I have written Item1, similarly at B5 Item2, B6 Item3 and B7 Item4

   2. After clicking at E4, I opened Data, Data Validation, and under settings tab in pop-up, I clicked Allow : List, in Source, I write down `=$B$4:$B$7`  . This creates a drop-down list, from which a user can select Item1 ,or Item 2 or Item3 or Item4 .
   3. I went to Sheet2, At D4, I wrote down "selected value" .
   4. At Sheet2,  E4, I write " `=Sheet1!E4`" .

Now whenever I go to sheet1 and change the list value , the corresponding value at sheet2 is automatically updated.

Hope this solves exactly what you are trying to do !

PS : This does not requires VB scripting.

Comment: Thank you for your response. :) But what i want to do is to select the list in Sheet 2 as well not just to display what was selected in Sheet 1. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You mean in drop down value, reference from Sheet1 comes, as well as there are some other values in drop down in sheet 2. And once user has selected something from sheet 1 in drop-down, you want drop-down value in sheet2 to be changed to that value selected in sheet1. ?  Please explain a bit more. I think by adding  combination of If conditions and properly selecting values, it can be done. Refer :  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267081/change-excel-drop-down-selection-based-on-status-of-another-column ) But the requirement needs more explanation to me.Can you give a example ?

Comment: Drop down lists in both sheets reference the same list (doesn't matter where it is stored). And yes, once the user has selected something from Sheet 1 drop down, when he browse in Sheet 2, he should be able to see the same selection and can also change the selection in Sheet 2 - affecting the selection in Sheet 1. It's like the logic in the drop down lists in web pages where we browses different pages yet our selection remains and also you are given the chance to change your selection wherever page you are. Hope this clearly explain my case. Thanks again! :)